# How do I delete multiple records with dependent records in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
create table foo (id, name, order, ...);
create table foo_bar (id, foo_id, name, value);
```

foo contains order column with values as (1,2,3,4,5,...10)
assuming foo_bar contains multiple records for each foo.

How do I delete foos whose order values are 3..6 and its dependent records?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars,  :dependent => :destroy
end

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :foo
end
```

If your relation is like above following code will work

```
Foo.delete_all(["id in (?)", [3,4,5,6]])
```

OR Just

```
Foo.delete([3,4,5,6])
```

Ref [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001800)

EDITED

From little i know your question i think you have something like following

foo table

```
id  some_column    order
1   some_value      3
2   some_value      4
3   some_value      3
4   some_value      2
5   some_value      1
6   some_value      5
7   some_value      6
```

foo_bar table

```
id  some_column    foo_id
1   some_value      2
2   some_value      1
3   some_value      3
4   some_value      2
5   some_value      4
6   some_value      5
7   some_value      6
```

Then user following `order` instead of `id`

```
Foo.delete_all(["order in (?)", [3,4,5,6]])
```

EDITED: Use [`destroy_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) to Destroys the records by instantiating each record and calling its {#destroy}[rdoc-ref:Persistence#destroy] method.

```
Foo.destroy_all(["order in (?)", [3,4,5,6]])
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the values are not id(s) but a different integer column in my table.

Comment: @priya, that doesn't matter. If you have `:dependent => :destroy` the dependent records will be deleted. The condition with which you delete the parent record doesn't make a difference. Well, it *shouldn't* make a difference. Have you tried this?

Comment: please note that this is NOT RECOMMENDED. It is very dangerous to do something like this, becuase one simple mistake and you can erase half of your database (if you have cascade dependent => destroy, like user has many articles, articles has many comments etc.). Suggested approach is to make a boolean flag "deleted". Also, you might want later to create statistics, if you just delete something like it never existed you wouldn't have such possibility.

Comment: `delete` and `delete_all` do not honor the `:dependent => :destroy` option on associations.  You should use `destroy` and `destroy_all` (which have performances implications)

Comment: @mkk I like the approach of flagging records instead of deleting them, and use it quite often.  It's not the perfect solution for all cases, though.

Comment: @Wizard of Ogz - I would definitely like to remove the records here, I guess we tried the delete_all / destroy_all options and none of them worked for us. Not sure what the problem is over here.

Comment: if you wanna be cool then the new syntax ----> dependent: :destroy             :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer, to destroy(delete) the dependens:

As @Salil said if your model has the `dependent callback` like this:

```
has_many :foo_bars,  :dependent => :destroy
```

Your query to destroy the parent and dependent records should be:

```
Foo.where(order: [1, 2, 3, 4]).destroy_all
```

The method `where` will get all records with the array of `orders` and call the `destroy` method for each record found.

**JUST USE `delete` or `delete_all` if you don't want to execute the callbacks about destroy dependencies.**